# Running an executable (.exe) within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, embed, frame, executable

I am currently working on a project in Java where we have to use an avatar created by someone else. This avatar is a graphical executable. It communicates with the Java application through xmlrpc.

I want to be able to run (embed) this executable within my Java application. I don't just want to execute the executable, I want it to actually be visible within the Java application.

I know this behavior is possible in C# (Process class), so I was wondering: is this also possible in Java?

The avatar in the application must be scalable.

Comment: Are you aware that an executable might not be executable on some other system (e.g. Linux cannot easily execute Windows `*.exe` programs) and that it may be a security risk? Also, executables are not required to give some graphic.

Comment: Well unless you have an emulator to run windows object code inside your java application, you **do** want *Windows* to run your executable. What do you mean by "being visible withing the java app." ? Do you want to get the output of the executable ? Take a look at `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch at this moment I am not concerned with multi-platforms, for the moment I am developping it for windows. As for executables in general, I am talking about a specific executable (an avatar) that starts fullscreen.

Comment: @zakinster I want the graphical output of the application. also, I am well aware what `Runtime.exec()` does, but I don't want two separate processes running (the avatar is fullscreen and interferes with the java application)

Comment: @bas How is it possible to do that in `C#` exactly ?

Comment: It's sure not possible on OS X or *nix!  If you only intend to support Windows, use C# & be done with it.

Comment: @zakinster http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project

Comment: @AndrewThompson using C# would mean redoing my entire project. I only want to do that if that is the only option.

Comment: @bas That's a nice trick but to do that you must use the Win32 API to build your interface, that's not possible in Java.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not saying it is any concern of yours. I am not posting it here because I demand an answer, I am just curious as to whether people know the answer. I'd rather have you not answer if your only goal is to patronize someone on their choice of language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`C#` example you gave](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project) uses a [Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) *trick* that uses [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the parent of the running embedded executable's main window from the `desktop window` to a newly created control. In order to do that, you would need to :

- Create a *WinAPI Window control* to contain your embedded executable
- Have access to the *Windows API* to get a handle on the running .exe main window
- Have access to the *Windows API* to use [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The problem is that **you don't have access to the Windows API in Java**. And even using [`JNI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or something like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) that would'nt be easy to do so since you don't have direct access to the *WinAPI Window control* created by the JVM (except using some undocumented windows-specific Sun API).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I wasn't sure but I feared this.