# Is there any way to run a foreign exe inside a window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm trying to run a application inside a JavaFX window. I found that quiet simple and easier to do it in Winform .NET by using "user32.dll".

For example: https://youtu.be/N6GWgxEvibE?t=164

How can I do like that in JavaFX?

Comment: Sorry, but I’m too busy to watch a video.  Please explain your goal in words.  Are you just trying to show the textual output of an external process in a window? Are you trying to run a program with its own desktop GUI encapsulated in a JavaFX window?  Are you trying to run a web application in a JavaFX window?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. That Q&A appears to only focus on the standard input/output/error streams, whereas the OP wants to embed _the GUI_ of a foreign executable inside a JavaFX window.

Comment: to use native library in java you can use java native interface (jni) or more generally java native access (jna). as an analog of user32.dll I think it is best to use jna.

Comment: @mrus Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358765/6395627) I believe trying to implement this would very much be non-trivial. Note, if this is possible, you'd have to use JNI (or JNA) in order to access the Win32 API and you'd probably have to access the internals of Java/JavaFX. This functionality would be Windows specific as well